# How to save a matrix in a tab delimited text file in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have aa: {2196017x1 cell} matrix in matlab which contains words. I want to save it in a tab delimited text. I use this code :

```
save f3.txt, aa;
```

but when I want to import this text file as a table in SQL Server , just show me some meaningless words and SQL fails. How to save this matrix which can be import as a table in SQL Server.

Comment: Did you look into `dlmwrite`?

Comment: @Suever It returns an error `Error using dlmwrite (line 118)
The input cell array cannot be converted to a matrix.`

Comment: You probably need to use `fprintf('%s\t', aa{:})` then